# Symlink problem

Tags: nfs, symlink

I'm trying to do a simple symlink. I have a nfs share shared under /share.
There are a couple of directories under /share. I wish to have a symlink of i.e.: /share/data in /var/opt/data.

I come to a problem when I use "ln -s /share/data /var/opt/data". I get a "symlink" in /var/opt/data that I cannot enter (root or not). In bash its coloured red. But when I create the symlink by using "midnight commander" its ok. It works like a charm.
The only difference I have spoted is that symlink done by "ln -s" is listed (ls -l) as "l" and it shows where the symlink point, but when I list midnightCommanders symlink then it's listed as "d" (directory I presume).
What's the difference ?
I need to do the symlink by a startup script so I need it "commandline".

There difference is also somewhere in having /share as an NFS share. It used to be a samba share and the it wasn't a problem. Switching to NFS started the problem. I have no problems with "/share" directory. It simply works, I also do other symliks (but to files not directories) and they work.

Any ideas ?

Comment: It looks like MC is doing a "hard link" instead of a "symbolic link". I thought hard links were not possible across different mounts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that there it was caseSensitivity problem. "/share" was mounted from samba server that has case sensivity off, now it's NFS so case sensitivity is an issue so my script (having an error) could not find the proper pathto the directory, making symlink unusable. There sill is a difference between "ln" and MC but both work at the moment.

I leave my question and it's anwser just as an example of simple human error.

THX (LatunSuD comment helped, cause I tried to create a hard link and it was the moment that file not exist error occured)